# How to select specific indices by condition using in python

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following array that contains 3 subarrays:

```
array([[1,3],[2,3],[4,5]],
      [[4],[7],[9]],
      [[0.3],[0.02],[-0.001]])
```

I want to create a new array that contains only the indices (in each subarray) that follow the condition: `abs(array[2]) < 0.1` - which means that I want to ultimately receive the output:

```
array([[2,3],[4,5]],
      [[7],[9]],
      [[0.02],[-0.001]])
```

Any suggestion for an efficient way to do that?

Comment: Your explanation is not crystal clear. Which axis do you use in your initial array? Can you send a snippet of code? It could help us inderstand

Answer (score 0):

I would do it that way:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[[1,3],[2,3],[4,5]],
      [[4],[7],[9]],
      [[0.3],[0.02],[-0.001]]])

b = [abs(item[0])<0.1 for item in a[2]]

c = [row[b] for row in a]
```

b is an array of booleans, defining which index to select